# How to set a session variable when a link is clicked?

Tags: 7, uri, sessions

I have created a search block. It outputs multiple results (names) as links.
User can follow the link. How can I pass the user name into $_SESSION variable?

I tried doing this, the result shows a *page not found* error.

```php
'name' => l(t($n['name']), 'edit_details' ,array('query' => array('uid' => $n['uid'])))
```

In `hook_menu()` I set `$items['edit_details/%']` to `array()`. I passed the value into the session with `$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['uid'];`.

Comment: Which Drupal version are you using?

Comment: i am using drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

Link URL :

```
 'name' => l(t($n['name']),'edit_details/@uid', array('@uid' => $n['uid']))
```

In hook_menu() :

```
$items['edit_details/%user'] = array(
    'title'          => 'Lets start',
    'page callback'   => '_get_user',
    'page arguments'  => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type'            => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

In callback :
In callback function you will get complete user object, as this wild card used for user core module.

```
function _get_user($user) {
  $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user->name;
  //Redirect to any other page you want.
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: The link url should be changed from 'user-check/@uid' to 'edit_details/@uid' so that it matches what is in the hook_menu. Also, don't forget that whenever you add/change a hook_menu you MUST clear your cache

Comment: As I  have mentioned it is not working. Can this be done with on click or an event listener.

Comment: 1) I have updated the answer. 
2) No, it cannot be done with js event handler.